# PHP - Multiple Table Row Fields JOINed to Single Table

Tags: php, mysql, join

Firstly I am not sure exactly how to word this Title. So I have two tables (heros and records). In the users table I have separated first and last name. In the records table I can have 1 to 2 users. How can a make the join on the same table? PS. I would like to display this on a table.

```
MYSQL heros table:
id|firstname|lastname
1 |Peter    |Parker
2 |Mary     |Jane

MYSQL records table:
id|badguy      |hero1id|hero2id
1 |Green Goblin|1      |
2 |Doc Oc      |1      |2
```

I would like to display my above information in a table (this will using html, css etc). I know how to do this I just do not know the correct way to JOIN using php.

```
Displayed table:
Heros & Bad Guys
Green Goblin | Peter Parker
Doc Oc       | Peter Parker and Mary Jane
```

PHP Code:
// Create a Query - records

```
$query = "SELECT records.*, heros.firstname, heros.lastname FROM records
        INNER JOIN heros
        ON records.hero1id = heros.id";
```

// Run Query

```
$records = $db->select($query);
```

Now I use the following code to display one of the names, how do I display the other without causing interference?

```
<td><?php echo $row['badguy']; ?></td> 
<td><?php echo $row['firstname']; ?> <?php echo $row['lastname']; ?></td>
```

Comment: Hello. Can you please edit your question and reformat it a bit? Its totally unreadable.

Comment: I saw that sorry. Is it any better now?

Comment: Much better. :) I'll take a look at your question in a few minutes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following sql. But still i would suggest to combine hero1id and hero2id as suggested by others.

SELECT records.badguy, GROUP_CONCAT(CONCAT(firstname, ' ', lastname) SEPARATOR ' and ') AS herosname
FROM records
INNER JOIN heros
ON records.hero1id = heros.id OR records.hero2id = heros.id
GROUP BY badguy

Comment: Thank you. I will try this now. How would I display this in my table? <?php echo $row['herosname']; ?>

Comment: You run the sql you will get the data as you required.

Comment: This has worked nicely so far. I hope it is just as effective when the amount or rows increases.

Answer (score 0):

### Update records table structure like that ##

MYSQL records table:
id|badguy      |hero1id|
1 |Green Goblin|1      |
2 |Doc Oc      |1      |  
3 |Doc Oc      |2      |

by using this strcture you can add unlimited number of users .please follow this table structure.

Comment: Thank you deep chand. But is there a way to do it the way I have described?

Comment: @nj167252 I think by changing the table structure it would be the most easiest way. There is another way, I can show it to you if you want, but its quite more complex

Comment: Please if you don't mind. The reason I don't want to do it the way deep answered because it will cause interferences later on.

Comment: but if you will have 20 users later than it will cause a big problem for you.but using my table structure you can add unlimited users.

Comment: What will the big problem be. Maybe if I understand I will consider changing, but fight now I think this is the only way. Bare in mind this example is a very simplified version of what I'm working with.